# Implementing general purpose long polling

Tags: node.js, long-polling

I've been trying to implement a simple long polling service for use in my own projects and maybe release it as a SAAS if I succeed. These are the two approaches I've tried so far, both using Node.js (polling PostgreSQL in the back).

### 1. Periodically check all the clients in the same interval

Every new connection is pushed onto a queue of connections, which is being walked through in an interval.

```
var queue = [];

function acceptConnection(req, res) {
  res.setTimeout(5000);
  queue.push({ req: req, res: res });
}

function checkAll() {
  queue.forEach(function(client) {
    // respond if there is something new for the client
  });
}

// this could be replaced with a timeout after all the clients are served
setInterval(checkAll, 500);
```

### 2. Check each client at a separate interval

Every client gets his own `ticker` which checks for new data

```
function acceptConnection(req, res) {
  // something which periodically checks data for the client
  // and responds if there is anything new
  new Ticker(req, res);
}
```

While this keeps the minimum latency for each client lower, it also introduces overhead by setting a lot of timeouts.

### Conclusion

Both of these approaches solve the problem quite easily, but I don't feel that this will scale up easily to something like 10 million open connections, especially since I'm polling the database on every check for every client.

I thought about doing this without the database and just immediately broadcast new messages to all open connections, but that will fail if a client's connection dies for a few seconds while the broadcast is happening, because it is not persistent. Which means I basically need to be able to look up messages in history when the client polls for the first time.

I guess one step up here would be to have a data source where I can subscribe to new data coming in (CouchDB change notifications?), but maybe I'm missing something in the big picture here?

**What is the usual approach for doing highly scalable long polling?** I'm not specifically bound to Node.js, I'd actually prefer any other suggestion with a reasoning why.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I like the approach of [PushPin](https://github.com/fanout/pushpin) (+ [explanation of concepts](http://blog.fanout.io/2013/04/09/an-http-reverse-proxy-for-realtime/)).

I love the idea (using reverse proxy and communicating with return codes + delayed REST return requests), but I do have reservations about the implementation. I might be underestimating the problem, but is seems to me that the technologies used are a bit on an overkill. Not sure if I will use it or not yet, would prefer a more lightweight solution, but I find the concept phenomenal.

Would love to hear what you used eventually.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned scalability, I have to get a little bit theoretical, as the only practical measure is load testing.  Therefore, all I can offer is advice.

Generally speaking, once-per anything is bad for scalability.  Especially once-per-connection or once-per-request since that makes part of your app proportional to the amount of traffic.  Node.js removed the thread-per-connection dependency with its single-threaded asynchronous I/O model.  Of course, you can't completely eliminate having something per-connection, like a request and response object and a socket.

I suggest avoiding anything that opens a database connection for every HTTP connection.  This is what connections pools are for.

As for choosing between your two options above, I would personally go for the second choice because it keeps each connection isolated.  The first option uses a loop over connections, which means actual execution time per connection.  It's probably not a big deal given that I/O is asynchronous, but given a choice between an iteration-per-connection and the mere existence of an object-per-connection, I would prefer to just have an object.  Then I have less to worry about when suddenly there are 10,000 connections.

The C10K problem seems like a good reference for this, though this is really personal judgement to be honest.

http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem